# Resource management

Tags: summation

Basically a vector where start with a capacity for `B` objects. When the vector runs out of space we reallocate with enough space for `$Br$` objects.

Thus Memory allocated for a vector is:

$$Br^n$$

Where

```
B:   Initial Value
r:   Growth factor
n:   Number of iterations of reallocation.
```

So after `n` iterations of reallocation. The amount of memory released will be:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Br^k$$

Assuming there is no other memory being allocated. The next allocation can reuse the released memory when:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Br^k >= Br^{n+1}$$

Note: Allocating for the next block `n+1`, can potentially use all previously released memory `n=>[0,n-1]` but not the currently used memory for step `n`.

Now I believe the is solvable (for some value of n) when:

$$r < \phi$$ or maybe $$r <= \phi$$

Unfortunately my math(s) is not good enough to prove/disprove this. What I have got is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Br^k >= Br^{n+1}$$
$$B.\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k >= Br^{n+1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k >= r^{n+1}$$
$${1-r^{(n-1)+1}\over{1-r}} >= r^{n+1}$$
$${1-r^n\over{1-r}} >= r^{n+1}$$

Now I am stuck.

Hopefully:

$$...$$
$$r^2 - r - 1 <= 0$$

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: of course it is not solvable with $r > 1$. at the beginning you have a finite amount of memory, at the end you have a arbitrary large allocated memory

Comment: @HenryW.: Sorry thought it was a standard maths number. 1.618 (approx). Aka [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)

Comment: $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ it is standard but $\phi$ is used for many other things

Comment: @user1952009: That's wrong. If you use a value r=1.5 it works fine (usually with N < 10 iterations). If you use a value r=2.0 it fails (as the memory needed grows faster than the released memory).

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your inequality (assuming $n \geq 2$ and $r > 1$ since these are the only relevant choices): \begin{align*}
    \frac{r^n-1}{r-1} \geq r^n  \\
    r^n-1 \geq r^n(r-1) \\
    r^n-1 \geq r^{n+1} - r^n  \\
    r^{n+1} - 2 r^n + 1 \leq 0  \\
    (r-2) r^n + 1 \leq 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}

If we differntiate the left-hand side with respect to $n$, we get a negative result, and we find that a solution for one value of $n$ is a solution for any larger value of $n$.

By inspection, both $r \geq 2$ is not a solution and $r = 2 - 1/2$ is a solution because $\frac{-1}{2} (3/2)^n \leq -9/8$, overpowering the $1$.  This suggests we get equality when $r$ is just a bit less than $2$, so set $r = 2-\varepsilon$.  Then $$ -\varepsilon r^n +1 \leq 0  \text{,}  $$
which is strict if $\varepsilon = r^{-n}$.  For $n=2$, this says $r = 2-r^{-2}$, which forces $r \approx 1.618$ (it's exactly the golden ratio, $\phi$).  For $n=3$, we have $r \approx 1.8$.  Continuing this analysis (using calculus and monotonicity of the derivative with respect to $n$), we would find that we have a slowly increasing upper limit for $r$ (upper bounded by $2$) as a function of $n$.

So, as long as $n \geq 2$, you can be sure that $r < \phi$ will work.  If you know that $n$ will be greater than some larger bound, you can be sure that a larger value of $r$ will work (but you can also be sure that no value of $r$ greater than or equal to $2$ ever works).